# Mysql big table multiple dates in where clause query performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have following table with 2 million rows in it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `gen_fmt_lookup` (
  `episode_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_type` enum('Audio','Video') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Video',
  `service_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `format_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `masterbrand_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `signed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `scheduled_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `scheduled_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `discoverable_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_discoverability_gn` (`media_type`,`service_id`,`genre_id`,`actual_start`,`scheduled_end`,`scheduled_start`,`episode_id`),
  KEY `idx_discoverability_fmt` (`media_type`,`service_id`,`format_id`,`actual_start`,`scheduled_end`,`scheduled_start`,`episode_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Below is query with explain which I am running against this table

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select   episode_id,scheduled_start 
from gen_fmt_lookup  
where media_type='video' 
and service_id in ('mobile_streaming_100','mobile_streaming_200','iplayer_streaming_h264_flv_vlo','mobile_streaming_500','iplayer_stb_uk_stream_aac_concrete','captions','iplayer_uk_stream_aac_rtmp_concrete','iplayer_streaming_n95_3g','iplayer_uk_download_oma_wifi','iplayer_uk_stream_aac_3gp_concrete') 
and genre_id in ('100001','100002','100003','100004','100005','100006','100007','100008','100009','100010') 
and NOW() BETWEEN actual_start and scheduled_end 
group by episode_id order by min(scheduled_start) limit 1 offset 100\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: nitro_episodes_gen_fmt_lookup
         type: range
possible_keys: idx_discoverability_gn,idx_discoverability_fmt
          key: idx_discoverability_gn
      key_len: 96
          ref: NULL
         rows: 31719
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

**So my questions are**

- Is the index used in query execution best? And if not can someone please suggest better index?
- Can mysql use composite index with 2 dates in where clause? As in the query above where clause has and condition "and NOW() BETWEEN actual_start and scheduled_end " but mysql is using index 'idx_discoverability_gn' with key length of 96 only. Which means it is using index upto (`media_type`,`service_id`,`genre_id`,`actual_start`) only.why can't it use index upto (`media_type`,`service_id`,`genre_id`,`actual_start`,`scheduled_end`) ?
- What else I can do to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

You have a range check, so a clustered index on (scheduled_start, actual_start, scheduled_end) might help. Your current indexes are not very useful.You can get rid of them and build one primary key (episode_id) and another index (service_id, genre-id, episode_id)

Comment: its denormalised table actually and episode_id is not unique in all rows.Only possible primary key is (`media_type`,`service_id`,`genre_id`,`actual_start`,`scheduled_end`,`scheduled_start`,`episode_id`)